# change style-sheet on locale change in NUXT

Tags: uikit, nuxt.js, vue-i18n

I am trying to change the style-sheet from `ltr` to `rtl` on locale change.
The site is on `UIKIT` ,  `vue-i18n` and `NUXT` .

[This](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/master/examples/dynamic-layouts) is the closest thing I found to what I want but still don't know how to work in out.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I added both style-sheets to the head and I ended up adding

v-bind:class="{'rtldir':($i18n.locale === 'fa')}"

to the my main layout div, to change the layout when the language is rtl